# Magento getfinalprice changing the function ()

Tags: magento

I would like to change the function of `getfinalprice` magento, does anyone know where is this file? I need to add some fixed costs in the calculation.

Thanks

Comment: Please close your question, since you already got an answer on Magento Stack Exchange. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15873/change-getfinalprice-function-magento Btw, why ask the same on both location at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

This is in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product which resides in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php.  To do what you asking and in a upgrade-friendly fashion, your modifications should be done in a custom module that overrides the product model. Modifying this method is a bit heavy handed though and my have unintended consequences.

[creating a custom module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) and 
[magento overriding](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

Comment: There is no need for rewriting. Magento core has a event for this 'catalog_product_get_final_price'.

Comment: @timhofman Both solutions work and are within the realm of best practices for magento development.  Down voting my answer is pedantic and childish.

Comment: Perhaps the -1 was a bit too much. Childish and pendantic? Lets agree to disagree on that part. But still, even while overriding is a practice. Searching for a proper event to inject your functionality is always the better way to go. That was my main message.